# How to make a table that has 3, 2 and 1 columns that fill the whole table?

Tags: html-table, html-email

> **Disclaimer:** I don't usually use tables for layouts but they seem to be the best options for html emails. Believe me, playing with divs
>   in emails sucks even worse. I'm looking for the best workaround, I
>   don't have much restraints as to how to design...

I'm almost there but I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
<table border=1 width="600px">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="140px">
      <td width="210px"></td>
      <td width="180px"></td>
      <td width="210px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="200px">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100px">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="300px">
      <td width="300px"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKL3r/embedded/result/)

My specific problem is with the last to cells, that I would like them to divide the space of the table by 50% each.

As you can see I modified the width of the last `<td>` to 300px (half of the table), but that also modifies the width of the first cell, which is an undesired result, I want the first three `td` to keep that 210px, 180px, 210px proportion.

Just in case to make it even more clear here is a sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with one table. The columns will always line-up. If this is for a layout for some other content, than you really need to look at div-based layouts.

If you have to use tables:

```
<table border=1 width="600px">
    <tbody>
        <tr height="140px">
            <td width="210px"></td>
            <td width="180px"></td>
            <td width="210px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="200px">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="100px">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="300px">
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="300"></td>
                        <td width="300"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not really a possibility, I know tables suck :) but this is for an html email layout... No workarounds?

Comment: No, because one of the two cells in the bottom row needs to span two columns `colspan=2`. But this will always cause that cell to span the same width as the two cells it is spanning from the row that has all three columns.

Comment: Although ... Let me post an answer

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically add another table into a single cell on the last row.

Comment: I had just popped into my head. I think that will do!! Let me give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

If you must use a table - and you really shoudldn't unless you are displaing tabular data - then the solution here, to my mind, is to make the top row one cell and to nest another table within it, of as many cells width as is needed. So:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2">
    <table><tr>
        <td width="210"></td>
        <td width="180"></td>
        <td width="210"></td>
    </tr></table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="50%"></td><td width="50%"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How'd I get a downvote the literal instant I post an answer? :(

Comment: Sorry, was too quick to click. I thought your code was wrong, but now see that you did what I did, only backwards.

Comment: Not sure, wasn't me :) I'll check your answer in a minute but I don't think it actually works since it will change the first `td` width too. 'll come back

Comment: No problem :) @Trufa, I'd imagine between Kevin's and mine is six of one and half dozen of another (the same, in other words). He typed more though :D

Comment: @Eamonn I hadn't seen that you actually made to tables, I'm sure I'll go with that solution thanks!! I'm playing around with it and see had it works in the different email clients...

Comment: The OP mentioned he's working with HTML email, and the mantra of HTML email is "Code Like it's 1996". So in this instance tables are, sadly, necessary.

Comment: @kgrote html 3 all the way :'(

Comment: +1 for correct answer, only accepted Kevin's because I think it came a little earlier, thanks a bunch!

Comment: lol - 3 mins later actually, but I hope it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a table where each column represents each possible division and then use colspans liberally.  So you have possible breaks at 210, 300, 490, & 600 for a total of 4 columns.

Then you'd want the first row to span 1, 2, 1, all of the full length to span 4, and then the half and half to span 2 and 2.

Comment: Not bad, I'll give it a try for sure!

Comment: It should be noted that this idea is roughly analogous to the idea of using a CSS grid layout for responsive design: you could define fixed width columns with a fairly small defined block size (in this case 50px could work decently) and then each cell could be made to span the appropriate number of columns to achieve the desired width.   This amounts to current practice retrofitted on to the old technology and would provide a roughly equivalent use.

Answer (score -1):

DIVs will be better solution here. Are you sure you need a table here? Maybe, divs?

Comment: Not really a possibility, I know tables suck :) but this is for an html email layout... No workarounds?

Comment: This isn't an answer.  And btw tables are still the backwards standard for email

Comment: @MattWhipple do you have experience with making client compatible emails? What would you suggest?

Comment: @Trufa I normally try to stay out of it, but I raid MailChimp and similar sites when I have the misfortune of getting sucked in.  I also generally push for formats that just flow vertically and use mobile friendliness to back me up.  In those cases you could avoid tables.

Comment: Yes, but the design is already set and there I don't have much of a call.